# I'm getting an error when create role in asp.net identity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

When I try to create new role in identity I get this error

> Value cannot be null.\r\n Parameter name: manager

This my controller code:

```
public ActionResult CreateUser(string Email,string Password)
{
    try
    {
        if (!(Email == null || Email == "" || Password == "" || Password == null))
        {
            IdentityUserModel UserModel = new IdentityUserModel();
            UserModel.Email = Email;
            UserModel.PasswordHash = Password;
            UserModel.UserName = Email;

            // Error happens on this line of code
            string userid = _authenticationService.CreateUser(UserModel);

            if (userid != null)
            {
                //bool result = _authenticationService.AddToRoles(userid,[])
                _authenticationService.CreateRole("مشتری");
            }

            var MessageFile = messageclass.ShowMessage((int)MessageClass.MessageKind.objectsavefilerror);

            return Json(MessageFile, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

and this my class :

```
public bool CreateRole(string rolename)
{
    var result = _roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(rolename));
    return result.Succeeded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem 
I forget add this code in bootstrapper.cs

```
private static RoleManager<IdentityRole> CreateRoleManager(IKernel kernel)
{
 return new RoleManager<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new UserManagementContext())); ;
}
```